# PostgreSQL Dynamic Number of Column Result

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have table like this

```sql
id   | firstname | lastname | object | total
--------------------------------------------
 1   | John      | Doe      | obj1   | 2
 2   | Mark      | Dew      | obj3   | 1
 3   | Steve     | Foey     | obj1   | 4
 4   | John      | Doe      | obj4   | 2
 5   | Mark      | Dew      | obj2   | 5
 6   | Steve     | Foey     | obj3   | 1
 --  | --        | --       | --     | --
 20  | Mark      | Dew      | obj10  | 1
```

and expect result like this:

```sql
id   | name       | obj1 | obj2 | obj3 | obj4 | .. | obj10 |
------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | John Doe   |   2  |   0  |   0  |   2  | .. |   0   |
 2   | Mark Dew   |   0  |   5  |   1  |   0  | .. |   1   |
 3   | Steve Foey |   4  |   0  |   1  |   0  | .. |   0   |
```

what the best solution (query) for my question? i'm new in sql. please help me. thank you.

Comment: What about the values for people that occur more than once? Should they be summed? Or do you want one row per id, not one row per person?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. they should be summed. Sabari's answer works for me. But i still curious with crosstab (still not works).

Comment: In that case: which `id` value do you want to see in the result. Sabari's answer includes the `id`  in the group by, so you will only see totals if one person has the same `id` for the same `object` (which doesn't seem to be the case for your sample data). What if you have id=42 and id=45 with the same object for e.g. John Doe? What do you want to see then?

Comment: I removed `id` and concat `firstname` and `lastname`. i havent tried with people with same `object` occur more than once.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NEW STYLE OF PIVOTING HOPE IT HELPS

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME ,LASTNAME  , CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ1') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ1' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END  AS OBJ1,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ2') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ2' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ2,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ3') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ3' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ3,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ4') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ4' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ4,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ5') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ5' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ5,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ6') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ6' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ6,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ7') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ7' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ7,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ8') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ8' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ8,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ9') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ9' IN  STR )+5 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ9,
 CASE WHEN POSITION ( 'OBJ10') IN  STR ) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE  SUBSTR( STR ,POSITION ('OBJ10' IN  STR )+6 ,1) :: INT END AS OBJ10
 FROM 
( SELECT ID, FIRSTNAME ,LASTNAME  , STRING_AGG(OBJECT :: TEXT || '$' || TOTAL ::TEXT ,',') AS 
FROM YOURTABLE 
WHERE OBJECT 
GROUP BY ID, FIRSTNAME ,LASTNAME )A
```

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql pivot is very simpler when used with filter clause.

```
  select
    first_name,
    last_name,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj1'),0) as obj1,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj2'),0) as obj2,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj3'),0) as obj3,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj4'),0) as obj4,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj5'),0) as obj5,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj6'),0) as obj6,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj7'),0) as obj7,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj8'),0) as obj8,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj9'),0) as obj9,
    coalesce(sum(total) filter(where object='obj10'),0) as obj10
  from table1
  group by first_name,last_name
```

Comment: its work! but how to replace `null` value with `0` ?

Comment: I have edited the answer and added coalesce(). This will replace null value with 0@JimJohnson

Comment: but.. i have a question. what if i add new person with new `object` ? lets say 'obj100'. how to make that query works without add `where object=obj100` to query?

Comment: I think if you need  "obj100" as one of the column then you must add "where object=obj100". Else you can make use of json type as column and data as (key,value) = (obj,total) .i.e.{ 'obj1': 5, 'obj2': 6,...'obj100': 8} for each person.